Cannot get template to work with lettrine
Cannot get this template to work with lettrine...
If I break it down to this minimal example, the error is still the same:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, openany]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{Hello}
\author{World}

\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Random Chapter}
\lettrine{L}{orem ipsum dolor sit amet}, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesentimperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien.

\end{document}

The error occurs in line 76 to 112 of lettrine.sty
\DeclareKeys[LettrineGlobal]
  {
    lines.code        = \setcounter{DefaultLines}{#1}   ,
    depth.code        = \setcounter{DefaultDepth}{#1}   ,
...

The error is as follows for all the lines:
l.78 ...ode = \setcounter{DefaultLines}{#1}
,
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
<recently read> ##
l.78 ...ode = \setcounter{DefaultLines}{#1}
,
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
##

I appreciate your helpful answer.

don't use external links, make a small complete example in your question. The code posted in the question runs without error so does not appear to be related to your question?

the code you link to on overleaf also runs without error producing this output  please show an example that produces the error that you show

you should show your log but perhaps you are using a modern letttrine.sty on an old tex in which case try \usepackage{lettrine}[=v2.0]  to force it to use an old version of the package

Many thanks for your answers @DavidCarlisle. The minimal example from the question does not work for me and produces the error. Your assumption with the old tex version and the new lettrine.sty file seems to be correct, with \usepackage{lettrine}[=v2.0] the whole thing works for now. Thank you very much!

you must have done something wrong, the old tex distribution that you have should have had an old compatible copy of lettrine.sty but I guess you have copied in a new version of lettrine.sty from somewhere?

You have not shown any log but it seems you are using an old tex system (with a latex older than 2020 I would guess).
That TeX system should have come with a compatible lettrine.sty and the example posted should work without error. However your error message shows that you are using a newer lettrine.sty that is using l3keys syntax.
The lettrine distribution contains some snapshots of old releases so you should be able to use
\usepackage{lettrine}[=v2.0]

to force an old version to load.
Unless your old distribution was a minimal installation that did not include lettrine a better solution would be to remove the new lettrine.sty that has been obtained from somewhere, and allow the older lettrine.sty that came with your tex distribution to be used.
